# Getting all the attached event handlers for a WPF control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing an application where I assign the events for the button dynamically. Now the thing is that I wish to get all the events for the button click event as I wish to remove the previous handlers.

I tried setting the event handler to null like:

```
Button.Click += null;
```

However I received a runtime exception that null cannot be assigned.

I wish to know the events which are already attached to it so that I can remove those events.

Can anybody help me in achieving this?

Comment: Are you sure you are working with WPF? [`System.Windows.Controls.Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) does not seem to have a `MouseClick` event, while [`System.Windows.Forms.Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx) [does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Sorry I missed that. Yes its indeed WPF. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: why are you clearing them out? All the subscribers are going to be very upset. Pretty much makes your control unusable

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I wish to clear them out and change the event handler for it (By assigning a new event handler to it.)

Comment: That is bass backwards. They could all be different handlers. It could be someone else's code. Sounds like you are abusing the mechanism. Can't tell why you went down this route, but you might be netter off hiding the event and then adding methods to access it, that make it very clear what is going on. I'd kick your ass ina code review if you did this to me.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I wish to remove the event handlers because at the runtime, I have used += to attach them. Now what happens is if I click on the button once, it fires it more than once (because it got assigned once more). I agree that its not the best way to do it, its an old code and nothing much can be changed.

Comment: To me, waht you want to do is a far more significant change than tracking down where the extra += happens and fixing it. if OnSomethingEvent == null) { OnSomethingEvent += SomeDelegate} say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign events - only attach (+=) and remove (-=) operations are available for clients.

Since += and -= are the only operations that are permitted on an event outside the type that declares the event, external code can add and remove handlers for an event, but cannot in any other way obtain or modify the underlying list of event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using -= to get it done. I just have to keep a count for how many times it is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

A nice pattern is to have an `Action removeAll` declared somewhere, so you can do:

```
button.Click += handler
removeAll += () => button.Click -= handler
```

That way you've only got one variable to keep track of, and you can clear everything just by calling `removeAll()`, rather than keeping track of all your handlers individually and having to call `-=` on each of them.  It's especially convenient if you've got multiple subclasses of `EventHandler` to deal with, since otherwise you'd have to keep track of them with multiple lists.

Answer (score 0):

For fruition, here is a major hack in all of its glory. You can modify it to get the exact list of events, and so forth.

Usage: `HasEventHandler(myCoolButton, "Click");`

```cs
    private static bool HasEventHandler(UIElement element, string eventName)
    {
        var events = element.GetType().GetEvents(Flags).Where(x => x.Name == eventName);

        foreach (var theEvent in events)
        {
            var fieldInfo = element.GetType().GetField($"{theEvent.Name}Event", Flags);
            RoutedEvent? eventKind = (RoutedEvent?) fieldInfo?.GetValue(element);
            if (eventKind is null)
                continue;

            // Look at the global event handlers store for any handlers.
            var store = typeof(UIElement)
                .GetField("EventHandlersStoreField", Flags)
                ?.GetValue(null); // `UncommonField<EventHandlersStore> EventHandlersStoreField`
            var method = store?.GetType().GetMethod("GetValue");
            var eventHandlersStore = method?.Invoke(store, new object[] { element });
            var getRoutedEventHandlers = eventHandlersStore?.GetType().GetMethod("GetRoutedEventHandlers");
            var handlers = (RoutedEventHandlerInfo[]?) getRoutedEventHandlers?.Invoke(eventHandlersStore, new[] { eventKind });

            if (handlers?.Any() == true)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that (fortunately. Just imagine, that some external code removes *your* event handler, and your code just stops working in silent manner).

(Reflection isn't an option here, because event implementation may be differ from type to type). Usually, if you want to remove all event handlers this way, this means design error.

Comment: Reflection might be an option in WPF, depending on how [`RoutedEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedevent.aspx) is implemented. (Design-wise, a problematic option, I agree.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: it doesn't matter, indeed. Imagine this madness - you're using a very standard class `Button`, and once your handler stops to fire.

Comment: @Dennis, I assigned a new event handler to the same button (After removing all the handlers).